# PowerShell winforms Tab selected index changed event

Tags: winforms, powershell-3.0

I have designed the GUI using WinForms in PowerShell as follows

```
Add-Type -Assembly 'System.Windows.Forms'

$form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form

$TabControl = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TabControl

$tabPage1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TabPage
$tabPage1.Name = "Tab1"
$tabPage1.Text = "Tab1"
$tabPage1.Width = 500
$tabPage1.Height = 500

$tabPage2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TabPage
$tabPage2.Name = "Tab2"
$tabPage2.Text = "Tab2"
$tabPage2.Width = 500
$tabPage2.Height = 500


$TabControl.TabPages.Add($tabPage1)
$TabControl.TabPages.Add($tabPage2) 

$TabControl.SelectedIndexChanged($TabControl_SelectedIndexChanged)

$TabControl_SelectedIndexChanged
{
    ({$selectedTab = $TabControl.SelectedTab;

    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($selectedTab)})
}
$form.Controls.Add($TabControl)
```

I would like to handle the selectedindex changed event but I couldn't, I got the following error with the above code

`Method invocation failed because [System.Windows.Forms.TabControl] does not contain a method named 'SelectedIndexChanged'.` so can some one help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out this is how I need to add the event

```
$TabControl.Add_SelectedIndexChanged({
    $selectedTab = $TabControl.SelectedTab
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($selectedTab.TabIndex)
})
```

instead of this

```
TabControl.SelectedIndexChanged($TabControl_SelectedIndexChanged)

$TabControl_SelectedIndexChanged
{
    ({$selectedTab = $TabControl.SelectedTab;

    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($selectedTab)})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe a bit late response, but this is the code you are maybe looking for :D

```
Add-Type -Assembly 'System.Windows.Forms'

$form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(610,360) 

$TabControl = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TabControl
$TabControl.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,0)
$TabControl.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(450,130)

$tabPage1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TabPage
$tabPage1.Name = "Tab1"
$tabPage1.Text = "Tab1"

$tabPage2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TabPage
$tabPage2.Name = "Tab2"
$tabPage2.Text = "Tab2"

$TabControl.TabPages.Add($tabPage1)
$TabControl.TabPages.Add($tabPage2) 

$TabControl.Add_SelectedIndexChanged({
    $selectedTab = $TabControl.SelectedTab
})

$form.Controls.Add($TabControl)

$form.Topmost = $True
$form.Add_Shown({$form.Activate()})
[void] $form.ShowDialog()
```

edit: Just saw this post:
[adding tabs section to powershell gui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68918318/adding-tabs-section-to-powershell-gui)